# Hibernate removed the grub

Tags: grub2, hibernate

I have a freshly upgraded 17.04 laptop (HP Probook 450G3), with only one OS instlled. I wanted to enable hibernation, so followed instructions from  here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

After the first command 'systemctl hibernate', when I tried to restart the system, it say:
BOOTMGR is missing.
Press CTRL+ALD+DEL to reatart.

I am traveling right now and have internet access only on my mobile phone. I can download the ISO and also have a USB pen drive. But don't have any bootable iso.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to, put Ubuntu onto your pen drive, as you probably did when installing Ubuntu; then boot from said USB on your laptop, and install and run a program called "Boot Repair" using these commands;

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Then click "Recommended Repair" and do as it tells you.

Comment: That's precisely the problem.  I am traveling I don't have access to the installable media. I can download the ISO on mobile / USB, but how do I create a bootable USB?